# JS unit testing: run tests on file changes (like nodemon)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, testing

I have two question on JS unit testing:

1) Is there some tool that allows to automaticaly run javascript unit tests when certain files are changed (like for example nodemon restarts node.js on js changes).

2) Is this strategy appropriate (efficient) way to run unit tests?

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: Try testem. It runs your unit tests continiously on file changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out grunt build system and the watch task. You can setup grunt to watch for file changes and then run any tasks you want (test, lint, compile, etc...).

https://github.com/cowboy/grunt

Some of the ideas are covered in this tutorial. http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/grunt-js-command-line-tutorial

Answer (score 18):

For those who are committed to using nodemon, `nodemon -x "npm test"` has worked for me.

#### A little explanation

`nodemon --help` says:

`-x, --exec app ........... execute script with "app", ie. -x "python -v".`

In our case `npm test` is set to run tests by configuring our package.json

For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
},
```

Answer (score 6):

When using jest, nodemon is not necessary. Simply set the `test` script command to `jest --watchAll` in package.json as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --watchAll"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "develop": "nodemon ./src/server.js --watch src --watch __tests__ -x \"yarn run test\"",
  "test": "mocha ./__tests__/**/*.js --timeout 10000" }
```

The `develop` script is my command line to run my express server (entry: `./src/server.js`), watch the `/src` directory which has all my server/API code, watch the `/__tests__` directory which as all my specs and lastly tells nodemon to execute the enclosed statement before each restart/run with `-x \"yarn run test\"`

`yarn run test` is no different than `npm run test`.  I prefer yarn over npm so that part is up to you.  What is important is the `\"` tags inside the JSON value... without it, it will fail since the argument will be tokenized incorrectly.

This setup allows me to trigger changes from either server/API code or writing/fixing specs and trigger full test run BEFORE restarting the server via nodemon.

Cheers!